# Calculate interval time using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the call waiting time (Hold time) during an interval of 30 minutes

**HoldTime is given in seconds**

***Input Data***

```
| Date     | ID    |StartDate | StartTime          |holdtime |
 ---------  ------- ---------- -------------------- ---------
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  10:03:46.0000000    62
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  10:36:42.0000000    189
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  11:06:54.0000000    65
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  11:11:46.0000000    79
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  11:19:55.0000000    118
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  11:38:20.0000000    36
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  12:13:46.0000000    67
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  13:45:27.0000000    24
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  13:52:59.0000000    144
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  15:02:43.0000000    39
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  16:00:41.0000000    246
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  16:54:22.0000000    79
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  16:59:18.0000000    94
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  17:29:19.0000000    84
28/12/2022  3110522 28/12/2022  17:54:44.0000000    64
```

***Output Data***

```
|ID    | StartDate |intervalStartTime | intervalStoptTime | holdtime
 ------  ---------  -----------------  ------------------- ----------
3110522 28/12/2022  10:00:00.000       10:30:00.0000000     62
3110522 28/12/2022  10:30:00.000       11:00:00.0000000     189
3110522 28/12/2022  11:00:00.000       11:30:00.0000000     262
3110522 28/12/2022  11:30:00.000       12:00:00.0000000     36
3110522 28/12/2022  12:00:00.000       12:30:00.0000000     67
3110522 28/12/2022  13:30:00.000       14:00:00.0000000     168
3110522 28/12/2022  15:00:00.000       15:30:00.0000000     39
3110522 28/12/2022  16:00:00.000       16:30:00.0000000     246
3110522 28/12/2022  16:30:00.000       17:00:00.0000000     121
3110522 28/12/2022  17:00:00.000       17:30:00.0000000     93
3110522 28/12/2022  17:30:00.000       18:00:00.0000000     107
```

I am making a function to split data, however I am not getting what I want. I think I'm doing something too complicated to solve it. Using a loop like WHILE is not something I like to use in SQL.

```
while (@eventDurationMins>0)
    begin
        set @eventDurationInIntervalMins = cast(@intervalEndTime-@eventStartTime as float)*24*60 ;
        if @eventDurationMins<@eventDurationInIntervalMins
                set @eventDurationInIntervalMins = @eventDurationMins ;
        insert into @retTable
        select @intervalStartTime,@intervalEndTime,@eventDurationInIntervalMins
        set @eventDurationMins = @eventDurationMins - @eventDurationInIntervalMins ;
        set @eventStartTime = @intervalEndTime;
        set @intervalStartTime = @intervalEndTime;
        set @intervalEndTime = dateadd(minute,@intervalMins,@intervalEndTime);
    end;
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I recreated the problem using EXCEL that's why I got some decimal places. But we can round them to the largest number (261,9999 -> 262)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just modified the example. Thank you

Comment: if you provide your data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: so, to clarify, you want to segment the `holdtime` to 30min windows? i think you can generate the desired start & end time then use `join` or subquery to collate the relevant `holdtime`.

Comment: Yes, Exactly segment the holdtime to 30 min windows. 
It could be a good idea.

Comment: Well I was going to take a look, but still no DDL+DML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They key here is to find the timeslot in 30 minutes. The `TimeSlot` computation is basically to "round down" the time to every 30 minutes. Example : from `10:00` to `10:29` round down to `10:00` etc

```
select ID, StartDate, 
       intervalStartTime  = TimeSlot, 
       intervalStoptTime  = dateadd(minute, 30, TimeSlot),
       holdtime  = sum(holdtime)
from
(
    select *, 
           TimeSlot = convert(time(0), 
                              dateadd(second, 
                                      convert(int, 
                                              datediff(second, '00:00:00', StartTime) 
                                              / 30.0 / 60.0) * 30 * 60, '00:00'))
    from   InputData
) i
group by  ID, StartDate, TimeSlot
```

---

Edit :

CTE numbers is just a [tally table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-1/). It is used to explode those rows where the `holdTime` span across multiple time slot

The holdtime (ht) is calculated in below case expression. First condition is where the hold time contains within same time slot. The remaining 3 conditions are to handle when the explode case

```
ht = case when n = 0 
          and  count(*) over(partition by [Date], [ID], [StartDate], [StartTime]) = 1
          then holdTime
          when n = 0
          then datediff(second, StartTime, dateadd(minute, 30, TimeSlot))
          when n = count(*) over(partition by [Date], [ID], [StartDate], [StartTime]) - 1
          then datediff(second, dateadd(minute, n * 30, TimeSlot), EndTime)
          else 30 * 60
          end
```

The query

```
with 
numbers as
(
    select n = 0
    union all
    select n = n + 1
    from   numbers
    where  n < 99
),
cte as
(
    select *
    from   InputData i
           cross apply
           (
               select EndTime  = dateadd(second, holdTime, StartTime),
                      TimeSlot = convert(time(0), 
                                         dateadd(second, 
                                                 convert(int, 
                                                         datediff(second, '00:00:00', StartTime) 
                                                         / 30.0 / 60.0) * 30 * 60, '00:00'))  
           ) t
           cross apply
           (
               select EndTimeSlot = convert(time(0), 
                                         dateadd(second, 
                                                 convert(int, 
                                                         datediff(second, '00:00:00', EndTime) 
                                                         / 30.0 / 60.0) * 30 * 60, '00:00'))  
           ) e
),
cte2 as
(
    select [Date], [ID], [StartDate], [StartTime], [EndTime],
           TimeSlot = dateadd(minute, n * 30, TimeSlot),
           ht = case when n = 0 
                     and  count(*) over(partition by [Date], [ID], [StartDate], [StartTime]) = 1
                     then holdTime
                     when n = 0
                     then datediff(second, StartTime, dateadd(minute, 30, TimeSlot))
                     when n = count(*) over(partition by [Date], [ID], [StartDate], [StartTime]) - 1
                     then datediff(second, dateadd(minute, n * 30, TimeSlot), EndTime)
                     else 30 * 60
                     end
    from   cte i
           inner join numbers n 
                   on n.n >= 0 
                  and n.n <= datediff(minute, TimeSlot, EndTimeSlot) / 30
)
select ID, StartDate, 
       intervalStartTime  = TimeSlot, 
       intervalStoptTime  = dateadd(minute, 30, TimeSlot),
       holdtime  = sum(ht)
from   cte2
group by ID, StartDate, TimeSlot
order by intervalStartTime
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/7knhg-Gw)

Comment: Thanks Squirrel, that is a good approach. Do you know how to take into account the remaining minutes when the operation was close to the interval? . For example: 16:59:18.0000000, duration 94 seconds.  Of the 94 seconds 42 seconds belong to the interval of 16:30 - 17:00. The others  52 seconds belong to the 17:00 - 17:30 interval.

Comment: Why `16:59:18` is group under both `16:30 - 17:00` and `17:00 - 17;30`? What is the logic here ?

Comment: I think I understand what you wanted. You  should have highlighted this in your original question